# Unnecessary locations for Spotlight indexing?

Tags: time-machine, spotlight, mds

I've noticed Spotlight using a lot of processor time and when I review where it's digging about via `sudo fs_usage mdworker mds`, I see that most of the time is being spent in `/System/Library/` and `/Library/` as well as some other places like `/opt/` for Homebrew and MacPorts.

I'm curious, has anyone compiled a safe list of paths/folders to exclude from indexing by Spotlight so as to reduce Spotlights indexing load and database size?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't found anything yet, but this script might prove useful to exclude, for example, all `node_modules`, all `.git`, all `Caches`, etc.: https://alexwlchan.net/2021/08/ignore-lots-of-folders-in-spotlight/